# How to compare two List<class> getting from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

let's say I have a table named Api, like this:

```
id | flag | audit
1  |   1  |   12
2  |   1  |   12
3  |   0  |   12
4  |   1  |  1234
5  |   1  |  1234
6  |   1  |  1234
```

with this code I can count `audit` column:

```
//DBHelper
public List<Contact> getaudit(){
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "select audit, count(audit) FROM Api group by audit";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setName((cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setAudit(cursor.getString(1));
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}

//MainActivity.java

List<Contact> contacts = db.getaudit();
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
    String log = "Audit Name "+cn.getName()+" ,Counting " + cn.getAudit();
    // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);
}
```

the logcat shows me:

```
Audit Name 12 ,Counting 3
Audit Name 1234 ,Counting 3
```

I will do a same code to get flag count with `group by audit`, so I have 2 List, but I don't know how to use `if statement` with 2 List<>

the problem is:

I want to compare if count `1` of flag is same as Audit with `group by` query, the Logcat will tell me `Same`

Like:

```
id | flag | audit
1  |   1  |   12
2  |   1  |   12  // audit 12 = 3(count) but flag = 2(count)
3  |   0  |   12
4  |   1  |  1234
5  |   1  |  1234 // audit 1234 = 3(count) and flag = 3(count) output Same
6  |   1  |  1234
```

Is there some way to do that?
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Audit, Count(Audit) AS AuditCount, Sum(Flag) AS FlagTotal FROM API  GROUP BY Audit
```

It will return

```
┌───────┬────────────┬───────────┐  
│ Audit │ AuditCount │ FlagTotal │  
├───────┼────────────┼───────────┤  
│ 12    │     3      │     2     │  
│ 1234  │     3      │     3     │  
└───────┴────────────┴───────────┘
```

And now you're able to compare the AuditCount with the FlagTotal on the same row.

Comment: the code works to count flag by audit, but how to add `if statement` like i want?

Comment: Possibly do that by code (Java), once the recordset has been retrieved.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you explaining more clearly sir?

Comment: By scanning the cursor, you can check if the next value equals the one you already checked. In this example, 3 doesn't equal 2. So, you won't get the "Same!" output.

Comment: i think we are on miss understanding sir, on my example, i have 3 `count of audit` but `2 count of flag=1` so nothing will do, but the 2nd `count of audit` equal to `count of flag =1` with if syntax, it must be `if (auditcount != flagcount){ nothing will do}`

Comment: In this case, you can't. You can't have 2 counts on 2 different columns and compare them with one another. Or, at least, nothing that comes to my mind, currently.

Comment: is there no other way sir?

Comment: As I said, I currently can't think of a direct way to do that.

Comment: at your return table, is it possible to add another column called `AuditCount` that count of Audit column sir?

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple aggregate functions. I called AudtCount FlagCount, because I misunderstood your original intention.

Comment: can you give me a query to do that, because i dont get when there's `where flag=1` clause

Comment: Glad to help. Hopefully, I contributed to your successful app!

Comment: Nice, comprehensive and very helpful information. Thank you.